# Integração PayPal SandBox não funciona!

Tags: php, pagamento-online

Olá, bom dia será que alguém pode me ajudar com um problema que estou tendo na integração Rest Api SDK da PayPal.

Eu coloquei o código abaixo, parece rodar perfeitamente, porém quando vou em "Transactions" no sandbox do paypal não aparece nenhuma transação. Alguém sabe me dizer o que é?

**CÓDIGO**

```
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;

require dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . "/autoload.php";

$api = new ApiContext(
    new OAuthTokenCredential(
        '{CLIENT_ID}',     // ClientID
        '{CLIENT_SECRECT}'      // ClientSecret
    )
);

$api->setConfig(
    array(
        'mode'                      => 'sandbox',
        'http.ConnectionTimeOut'    => 30,
        'log.LogEnable'             => false,
        'log.FileName'              => '',
        'log.LogLevel'              => 'FINE',
        'validation.level'          => 'log'
    )
);

/**
 * Payer

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$item = new Item();
$item->setName('Item 1');
$item->setCurrency('USD');
$item->setPrice('2');
$item->setQuantity(1);

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item));

$details = new Details();
$details->setSubtotal('2');

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD');
$amount->setTotal('2');
$amount->setDetails($details);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount( $amount );
$transaction->setItemList($itemList);

$urls = new RedirectUrls();
$urls->setReturnUrl('{URL}');
$urls->setCancelUrl('{URL}');

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale');
$payment->setPayer($payer);
$payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));
$payment->setRedirectUrls($urls);

try {
    $payment->create( $api );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e);
}

header("location:" . $payment->getApprovalLink() );
```

Consigo finalizar a "compra" normalmente com o usuário comprador que o sandbox criar, porém nada de aparecer as transações.

Comment: OLá, dentro da sua integração você está fazendo o DoExpressCheckoutPayment corretamente ? Porque se não estiver o pagamento é processado normalmente, mas internamente ele não é concluído. Recomendo que verifique o seu DoExpressCheckoutPayment, e tente novamente!

Comment: Tudo que você precisa saber sobre integração com Express Checkout dentro do brasil, é possível encontrar no site do PayPal, por exemplo https://www.paypal-brasil.com.br/desenvolvedores/tutorial/guia-de-integracao-rapida-usando-express-checkout/ aqui tem uma documentação bem explicativa de como funciona o fluxo e como deve ser o seu DoExpressCheckoutPayment. Depois me diz se deu certo, tudo bem ?